# is the pickit4 compatible with PICkit 44-Pin Demo Board (PIC18F45K20)

Tags: pickit

can I use the pickit4 with the PICkit 44-Pin Demo Board (PIC18F45K20), is it just a matter of aligning the pins with the arrow ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just align the arrows.

Microchips programming interface ICSP typically uses a 6x1 pin header, whereof the last pin is not used. The pickit 4 has an 8x1 header, where the additional pins are used for different modes of operation like JTAG.